# Given $x^3-120x+p$, find all $p$ that make the polynomial reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers

Given a polynomial $$x^3-120x+p$$, where $p$ is a prime number, how do you find all $p$ values that make the polynomial reducible in the rational numbers?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: This polynomial is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ if and only if it has a root in $\Bbb Q$. By the rational roots theorem, the only possible rational roots are $\pm p,\pm1$ since $p$ is prime.

Comment: What did you attempt yourself before the comments were posted?

Comment: When I used the rational root test and plugged -p and p in for x and set the equation equal to 0, I got p=0, p=sqrt(119) and p=sqrt(121)...both positive and negative square roots. Neither of which would be prime numbers. So I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Oh I see what I missed. I forgot to use positive and negative 1. Now I get p= positive and negative 119. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$p=x(120-x^2)$ for an integer $x$, which gives $x\in\{1,-1\}$ or $120-x^2\in\{1,-1\},$

which gives $x=-11$ and $p=11$.